# How to change the position and rotation of a Colorscale in folium?

Tags: python, folium

In folium, I have a map with a GeoJson overlay. These overlays are colored differently using a branca colorscale, which is also visible on the map:

colorscale in wrong position
[image: colorscale in wrong position]

However, I'd like to have the colorscale be in a different position (at fixed coordinates) and rotated by 90 degrees:

colorscale in right position and rotation
[image: colorscale in right position and rotation]

Is this possible in folium?

Or would it be more viable to export the colorbar as a png image and add it as an ImageLayer?

I searched the folium and braca documentation, but found no hints.

Comment: Images can be added in the following ways. [https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/FloatImage.ipynb](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/FloatImage.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that changing the position/rotation of the colorscale is not possible in folium (see [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1605)). Leaflet, which folium is based on, provides a method for changing the colorscale's position in a rather coarse-grained way ([`Control.setPosition`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-setposition), which only accepts arguments like "topright"), however this interface is not exposed in folium. Changing the rotation is not supported at all.

I've found a workaround which I'll post below for the sake of completeness. If anyone else faces the same problem, the code will most likely have to be edited. However, it may serve as a starting point. Running the code requires `docker` to be installed.

```py
def add_colorscale(colorscale, map, x, y):
    # Make a blank figure and add the colorscale to it
    fig = folium.Map(tiles=None)
    folium.TileLayer(opacity=0).add_to(fig)
    colorscale.add_to(fig)
    # Save figure as HTML
    fig.save("temp/temp.html")
    # Make background transparent
    os.system("sed -i 's/top: 0.0%;/top: 0.0%; background: transparent/' temp/temp.html")
    # Convert the HTML to SVG
    os.system('docker run -v "$(pwd)/temp:/temp" fathyb/html2svg --wait 5 --format svg "file:///temp/temp.html" > temp/temp.svg')
    # Make the background transparent again
    os.system("sed -i 's/<rect fill=\"white\"/<rect fill=\"rgba(0,0,0,0)\"/' temp/temp.svg")
    # Rotate the SVG (please adjust the numbers by which the graphic is translated depending on your use case)
    os.system("sed -i 's/<use href=\"#group_0\"/<use href=\"#group_0\" transform=\"rotate(-90) translate(-2400 200)\"/' temp/temp.svg ")
    # Load the rotated SVG and add it at the specified position in the map
    with open("temp/temp.svg", "rb") as f:
        b64colorscale = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode("utf-8")
    FloatImage('data:image/svg+xml;base64,{}'.format(b64colorscale), bottom=y, left=x).add_to(map)
    # cleanup
    os.system("rm temp/temp.svg temp/temp.html")
```

This code than then be called to add a colorscale to an existing map:

```py
add_colorscale(colorscale, m, 0, 0)
```